# Messages passed to success url of django Update View

Tags: django, class, django-views, message

Im trying to pass a success message on update using the generic CBV UpdateView..

```
class TribeUpdate(FormMessagesMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Tribe
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'cause']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    form_valid_message = 'success'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('tribe_detail', kwargs={'tribe_slug' : self.kwargs['slug']} )

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(TribeUpdate, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not obj.creator == self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tribe = Tribe.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        action.send(tribe.creator, verb='updated the tribe', target=tribe)
        form.save()
        return super(TribeUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The success message doesnt apear on the success url page.. the tribe_detail view.. it just appears again when i click through to the UpdateView..?

Any help will be amazing, I need to override form_valid to save data to the form depending on the input..

Comment: What is the template for the success view, tribes detail? Age you sure you are including messages on it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your form_valid method you call itself again, so it goes in recursion.

You just need to overwrite

```
return super(TribeUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And it will work.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. this doesn't seem to be the problem, the message is not set on the success url view still

Comment: @AndrewBlaney and do you have django messages app enabled? Do you have django message template code included in success page template? Will it work if you add messages.success(self.request, 'success') inside get_success_url method?